# How do I run my C# Unit Test Cases using Jenkins?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, jenkins

I have prepared few Unit Test cases using Selenium-C# and MS Unit Test framework for a web application.

I am using Selenium WebDriver for automation. My tests run perfectly fine when I run them using Test Explorer (Visual Studio 2017). My tests take test data using Excel which is  present in the project path.

I want to run my tests using Jenkins which I have installed on my local machine. I have tried using MSTest Plugin for Jenkins and provided all the necessary paths as well, but upon running the same I get message as 'No Tests to execute'.

Is there any way to achieve this automated testing using Jenkins?

Note: I have restored all the Nuget packages before the build using Windows Batch Command and then the build using MSBuild.exe

Comment: I have used [this link](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/) to configure Jenkins with Selenium WebDriver automation.